# Cannot connect to Samba share via VPN

Tags: vpn, server-message-block, wireguard

I have a Wireguard site-to-site VPN that connects successfully.

- I can ping the remote Samba server using it's IP address 192.168.30.1
- I **cannot access** a share over the VPN tunnel using its IP address \\192.168.30.1\disk

Some background;

- Two ASUS routers configured with a wireguard site to site VPN.
- router A; the VPN server has 192.168.30.1
- router B; the VPN client has 192.168.20.1
- Router A has a shared USB disk accessible via Samba via \\192.168.30.1\disk
- from the 192.168.30 network, the samba share is accessible
- I access the share via a windows 11 client, no firewall, the windows client is able to browse other samba shares

Previously I had the same setup with OpenVPN, I could access the remote samba share via \\192.168.30.1\disk. But the performance was very bad, that's why I want to give wireguard a go...

I can ping computers in the 192.168.30 network from the 192.168.20 network.

I can access HTTP pages on the 192.168.30 network from the 192.168.20 network...

It puzzles me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samba over OpenVPN - horribly slow](https://serverfault.com/questions/264922/samba-over-openvpn-horribly-slow)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself;

1. You need the custom Merlin firmware on your ASUS router, and enable the JFFS option
2. Enable SSH to your Asus Router
3. Copy /etc/smb.conf /jffs/etc/smb.conf
4. edit /jffs/etc/smb.conf and add the network 192.168.20.x like so; hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.30.254/255.255.255.0 192.168.20.254/255.255.255.0

Strange thing stays, for OpenVPN this was not needed. Speed is a little better tho...

Answer (score 0):

Might be answered in [Samba over OpenVPN - horribly slow](https://serverfault.com/questions/264922/samba-over-openvpn-horribly-slow) already.

Comment: That's a work around, a nice alternative to read. But my question is; why I cannot acces smb over over wireguard. You answered the question; why is OpenVPN slow.